# Get column names and data to rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I have a table with basic employee details as below:

Table: tblEmployees

```
EmpID   Name    Contact   Sex
100     John    55555     M
200     Kate    44444     F
300     Sam     88888     M
```

I would like to get my query result as follows of a particular employee where `EmpID = 200`

```
Col1    Col2
EmpID   200
Name    Kate
Sex     F
```

Comment: What data type should `Col2` be? [`SQL_Variant`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? The ever popular `NVarChar(max)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use  cross apply:

```
select t.*
from employees e
cross apply (values 
    ('empid', cast(empid as varchar(100))),
    ('name', name), 
    ('sex', sex)
) t(attr, value)
where e.empid = 200
```

Presumably, `empid` is a number, so explicit casting is needed (otherwise sql server will try to cast the name and sex to numbers, which will fail).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=07473dcba16666d2fcad43c181b04b36)**:

```
attr  | value
:---- | :----
empid | 200  
name  | Kate 
sex   | F
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is with a little XML

**Full Disclosure:**  Not as performant as GMB's `CROSS APPLY` (+1) or `UNPIVOT`.  BUT it will dynamically unpivot virtually any row, table, view or ad-hoc query without actually using dynamic SQL.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([EmpID] varchar(50),[Name] varchar(50),[Contact] varchar(50),[Sex] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (100,'John',55555,'M')
,(200,'Kate',44444,'F')
,(300,'Sam',88888,'M')

 Select A.EmpID
       ,C.*
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (convert(xml,(select a.* for XML Raw ))) ) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
                 From  XMLData.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
                 Where xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)') not in ('EmpID','Other','Columns2Exclude')
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
EmpID   Item    Value
100     Name    John
100     Contact 55555
100     Sex     M
200     Name    Kate
200     Contact 44444
200     Sex     F
300     Name    Sam
300     Contact 88888
300     Sex     M
```

**EDIT - If Interested Here a TVF approach**

```
Select A.EmpID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-XML-UnPivot-Row]((Select A.* for XML RAW)) B
```

**The TVF**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-XML-UnPivot-Row](@XML xml)
Returns Table 
As
Return ( 
        Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
              ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
         From  @XML.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a less sophisticated solution involving 3 UNIONs, assuming the field names are predetermined in advance. This might perform better on large tables.
If you have performance issues, analyze the execution plan and make sure indexes are utilized optimally.

Since you are only looking for one particular employee at a time:

```
SELECT 'empid', convert(varchar(12), EmpID)
FROM tblEmployees
WHERE EmpID = 200
UNION ALL
SELECT 'name', name
FROM tblEmployees
WHERE EmpID = 200
UNION ALL
SELECT 'sex', sex
FROM tblEmployees
WHERE EmpID = 200
```

The first line does `convert(varchar(12)` under the assumption that EmpID is an `int` field.